# Should we rename the [religious-sites] tag to [religion-sites]?

Tags: discussion, meta, retag-request

There's a meta-tag called [religious-sites](/questions/tagged/religious-sites), which is used when asking about the faith-based sites.

In my opinion, [religion-sites](/questions/tagged/religion-sites) would be a better name for the tag.

---

It's hard to explain why the second version feels better for me. My explanation, to be honest, kinda hurts my case here:
Even though
*religious* does mean "of, relating to, or devoted to religious beliefs" ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/religious)), it has the primary meaning of "relating to or manifesting faithful devotion to an acknowledged ultimate reality or deity." It seems to me that when we say *religious sites*, we're saying that the sites, and thus the people on them, are religious- not that the site is for asking about religion.
(I may be overthinking this.)

---

Tag-synonym-creation is really awful, and I'm not *really* certain we need to do this, so here's a post to discuss whether we ought to change the tag.

Comment: Actually - the current iteration of Tag synonym tools are really good. They removed a LOT of the pain points IMO during the last update of them. Worry about the merits, not if we need to say a prayer before hitting the button that does scary, hard to fix stuff :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek when was that last update? Did something change recently?

Comment: Quite a while back. A keen user might notice I stopped complaining about it because right *now*, its impossible to do a synonym the wrong way, it confirms what you're about to do, and generally is in a state where its absolutely fit for purpose, least from a moderator point of view,

Comment: Example of 'religious sites' vs 'religion sites': 'On Stack Exchange we have religious sites' vs 'On Stack Exchange we have sites about religion' (IMO the tag change feels better and more descriptive)

Comment: I guess [this FAQ meta post on Christianity.SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/20224) describes the difference: "***This is a secular site.***"

Answer (score 6):

[Redz's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1218417/redz) [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393337/should-we-rename-the-religious-sites-tag-to-religion-sites#comment1315581_393337) nicely illustrates the difference between the current and proposed tags, and since this request has been received fairly well (+17/-0), I think we can move forward with the retagging.

Because there are only 5 questions with the current tag, this can probably be done pretty painlessly. I've gone ahead and created the tag, and plan on linking this question in the edit summaries. If anyone has an objection, we can re-evaluate.

Comment: Hey, it looks like there are still two questions with the old tag. Are you planning to finish the job, or shall I?